# How install sf R's package or GDAL at CentOS 6.8

Tags: r, centos, gdal, r-sf

I'm trying to install sf package on R in a server CentOS 6.8, by line command, with:

```
install.packages('sf', dependencies = TRUE)
```

And I got this error message:

```
> install.packages('sf')
Installing package into ‘/usr/lib64/R/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/sf_0.7-1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 8330564 bytes (7.9 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 7.9 MB

* installing *source* package ‘sf’ ...
** package ‘sf’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
configure: CC: gcc -m64 -std=gnu99
configure: CXX: g++ -m64 -std=gnu++0x
checking for gdal-config... /usr/bin/gdal-config
checking gdal-config usability... yes
configure: GDAL: 1.7.3
checking GDAL version >= 2.0.0... no
configure: error: sf is not compatible with GDAL versions below 2.0.0
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘sf’
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/sf’

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/RtmpKDXg4S/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
Warning message:
In install.packages("sf") :
  installation of package ‘sf’ had non-zero exit status
```

Looks like that I need to upgrade the GDAL to 2.0.0 or later, but I don't know how to do this. I'm looking for instalation (or even upgrade) by command line on CentOS and got nothing.

Any help will be apreciated.

Tks

Comment: You might have to request the admins to upgrade GDAL. If you go to the command line and try `module avail GDAL` you can see what versions of GDAL are available. You might have a newer version available that isn't loaded by default.

Comment: When I type it I get nothing : `[root@sistemas ~]# module avail GDAL
[root@sistemas ~]#`

Comment: You can build it [from source](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadSource) or try an rpm, but I don't see any >1.9.x for `CentOS 6.8`. The `Red Hat` [versions are old](https://rpms.remirepo.net/rpmphp/all.php?what=%25g), which I imagine are same/similar to CentOS.

Comment: @LucasBicalho: type `module avail` only

Comment: @LucasBicalho: the best solution is to request updating `gdal` to the latest version. While you are at it, requesting updating `proj` and `geos` too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those who landed on this page hoping to find instructions for installing "sf" on RHEL 7.5:

```
wget http://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/u/udunits2-2.2.20-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
wget http://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/u/udunits2-devel-2.2.20-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
yum install udunits2-devel-2.2.20-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
yum install udunits2-2.2.20-2.el7.x86_64.rpm

wget http://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/g/geos-3.4.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
wget http://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/g/geos-devel-3.4.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
yum install geos-*

wget http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/2.4.1/gdal-2.4.1.tar.gz
tar -zxvf gdal-2.4.1.tar.gz
cd gdal-2.4.1; 
./configure; make -j4; make install
echo "/usr/local/lib" /etc/ld.so.conf.d/libgdal-x86_64.conf
ldconfig
cp -p /usr/local/lib/libgdal.so.20* /usr/lib64/

cd ../
wget http://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/p/proj-4.8.0-4.el7.x86_64.rpm
wget http://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/p/proj-devel-4.8.0-4.el7.x86_64.rpm
yum install proj-4.8.0-4.el7.x86_64.rpm proj-devel-4.8.0-4.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

Some lines might be redundant however this has worked for me.

Comment: Trying out your solution. Will leave another comment should it work on RHEL 7.6. This is a pain in the arse haha

Answer (score 0):

You need the latest GDAL version. The package documentation suggest using docker
https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30965498)